# Automapper - Map list of string to list of object with string property

Tags: c#, automapper, automapping

I have problem with **automapper**

Here I have two objects:

Object 1:

```
public class First
{
    ......

    public IList<string> ImportantList{ get; set; }

    ......
}
```

Object 2:

```
public class Second
{
    .....

    public IList<ImportantListClass> ImportantList{ get; set; }

    .....
}
```

class:

```
public class ImportantListClass
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I try to use automapper to map First object to Second but my destination ImportantList is Empty. I have the same number of object in destination class but Name property is null.

I try:

```
CreateMap<Second, First>()
            .ForMember(z => z.ImportantList, map => map.MapFrom(z => 
             z.ImportantList.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()))
            .ReverseMap();
```

But it not change anything Is their any better way to do this

@EDIT

I ADD this:

```
        CreateMap<First, Second>();
        CreateMap<ImportantListClass, string>()
            .ConvertUsing(source => source.Name);
        CreateMap<string, ImportantListClass>()
                .ForMember(z => z.Name, z=> z.MapFrom(d => d));
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ConvertUsing` and add a map from `ImportantListClass` to `string`:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Second, First>();
    cfg.CreateMap<ImportantListClass, string>()
    .ConvertUsing(source => source.Name);
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var second = new Second
{
    Id = 22,
    ImportantList = new List<ImportantListClass>
    {
        new ImportantListClass { Name = "Name1" },
        new ImportantListClass { Name = "Name2" }
    }
};

var first = mapper.Map<First>(second);
```

Comment: `d` should be `source` :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu no problem, I modified the parameter name